# Background image multiple switch

Tags: c#

I have a program for my class where we have dice that are being rolled when you click a button.

I have the code working, but I am trying to make the dice rotate through the numbers and "stop" in the correct number.

I have a picturebox and when you click the button it shows a background image depending on what the random number generates.

Now if I wanted the first dice to flip through 20-30 images then stop and the 2nd to rotate through 30-40 images than stop... how would I accomplish this?

I tried so the image changes a few times... but it obviously has no delay so it ONLY shows the last image.

```
    public void DiceTwoDisplay(int _numberTwo)
    {
        if (_numberTwo == 1)
        {
            DiceRotate();
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die1;
        }
        else if (_numberTwo == 2)
        {
            DiceRotate();
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die2;
        }
        else if (_numberTwo == 3)
        {
            DiceRotate();
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die3;
        }
        else if (_numberTwo == 4)
        {
            DiceRotate();
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die4;
        }
        else if (_numberTwo == 5)
        {
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die5;
        }
        else if (_numberTwo == 6)
        {
            DiceRotate();
            imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die6;
        }
    }

    public void DiceRotate()
    {
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die1;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die2;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die3;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die4;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die5;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die6;
    }
```

I want it to show all of them real quick and then STOP on the last one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this [array thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Comment: Do you have anything to post as code or do you want us to guess it?

Comment: Added what I have so far for the 1 dice, same thing for the 1st dice just calling different picture box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timer = new Timer(50); // Set up the timer for 50 ms

_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);

_timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
```

Have some fields to represent the dies, plust a random number g enerator:

```
Image[] dies = new Image[] { die1, die2, die3, die4, die5, die6 )
Random r = new Random();
```

And your elapsed handler could be:

```
void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // you have to execute this on UI thread
    imageDie2.BackgroundImage = dies[r.Next(5)];// 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add thread sleep:

```
public void DiceRotate()
    {

        int milliseconds = 2000;

        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die1;
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die2;
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die3;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die4;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die5;
        imageDie2.BackgroundImage = die6;
    }
```

(or put the delay in the method or w/e you want)

Comment: If he executes that on UI thread this will not render anything as it will blokc the ui thread for the whole of that method, until it reaches to the end. This would have to be executed on another thread, with seeting of BackgroundImage only done on UI thread

Comment: But if the thread stops, the UI won't update..... so he wont ever see the image...

Comment: And his current problem is that he doesnt see all the images because they are instant, and the UI thread is blocked while changing each image

Comment: Arrgggghhhh..... Noone should use this (Maybe I am wrong. Every one should try it to see why it wouldn't work. )

Comment: It seems to me that he WANTS the UI to stop. donno why u down voted whoever did. This is a simple solution using the code he wrote. It will change picture, delay, change next picture, delay, while stoping the UI. He didn't say he wants the user to do actions while the dice is rolling.